# Why base class property is getting serialized in last?

Tags: c#, json

I have a base class

```
public class ParentSystemInfo
{
    private  string _Version = "R8.1";

    public SystemInfo()
    {

        this.Version = _Version;
    }

    }
    public string Version {

        get { return _Version; }
        set { _Version = value; }
    }    
}
```

I am inheriting it in another class

```
 public class ChildSystemInfo : ParentSystemInfo
{

    public ChildSystemInfo () :base()
    {

        this.MYInfo= new MYInfo();

    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MYInfo MYInfo{ get; set; }      
}
```

When i serialize this class i get parent property in end of json not at start. why is this happening and how can i prevent it.

Comment: Why do you need it in different order? Do you have problem reading tchem in software?

Comment: Yes i need to have arent property appear first. I need to understand why it is behaving so and how can i fix it aprat from creating a custom class for it

Comment: Are you referring to the order in the serialized data?

Comment: The order of keys present in JSON should be irrelevant to any standard-compliant parser. Though, I believe the reason is just that it's the last alphabetically – `M < N < V`.

Comment: Reason why you have your parent and the end is because serialisation order is from top class to bottom, no from the deepest child/derived class. You could try changing order by applying Order attribute

Comment: It is so funny that so many people in json related questions answer with "order should be irrelevant". whitespace and newlines are irrelevant too, but we add them. Because the whole point of json is to be human readable. Thus you want to enforce an order of properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Json property attribute to control the order in which attributes are being serizlied. See documentation here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyOrder.htm

So you would have:

```
public class ParentSystemInfo
{
    private  string _Version = "R8.1";

    public SystemInfo()
    {
        this.Version = _Version;
    }

    // Setting the JsonProperty to be -1 will ensure it appears before
    // all properties for which this attribute was not set.
    [JsonProperty(Order = -1)]
    public string Version {
        get { return _Version; }
        set { _Version = value; }
    }    
}
```

Comment: if there is another property which i want it come next to  then what order shall it set on it

Comment: By next, do you mean right after it? Think about it this way - for any property for which you don't specify the order, it is set as 0. Properties with the same order are serialized in some order which you do not control. Otherwise, properties are shown from smallest order to largest. So you could have the order of your first property as -2 and the second property as -1, and so on.

Comment: I have done as said the property with order -2 comes first but property with minus 1 comes at . why is it not coming at 2nd place ?